# similar inputs doesnt pass at same condition

Tags: python, timestamp

I need to calculate the time difference between timestamps of specific messages based on certain conditions, but I've run into a snag in my logic. The main issue arises when my even_messages are received on Fridays, and the subsequent response comes on a day other than Monday, even though this scenario is not accounted for in my conditions.

I was expecting that in these cases, my data would be processed in Block 3, and all the necessary transformations would be applied.

```html
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        
        if row["interaction_count"] % 2 == 0:

            if previous_odd_timestamp:
                even_time = row["timestamp"]
                odd_time = previous_odd_timestamp
                

                print(odd_time, row['interaction_count'])

                
                if odd_time.hour >= 8 and odd_time.hour < 19 and odd_time.weekday() < 5 and odd_time.weekday() == even_time.weekday():

                    print("phase 1: line", row['interaction_count'])

                   
                    time_diff = (even_time - odd_time).total_seconds()/60

                    time_diff_list.append(time_diff)

                    df.at[index, 'time_difference'] = time_diff
                
                elif odd_time.hour <= 8 and odd_time.weekday() <= 4 and odd_time.weekday() == even_time.weekday():

                    print('phase 2: line', row['interaction_count'])


                    odd_time = odd_time.replace(hour=8, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
                    
                    #
                    time_diff = (even_time - odd_time).total_seconds()/60

                    time_diff_list.append(time_diff)

                    df.at[index, 'time_difference'] = time_diff


                if 8 < odd_time.hour < 19 and odd_time.weekday() >= 4 and odd_time.weekday() != even_time.weekday():

                    print('phase 3: line ',row['interaction_count'])
                    

                
                    odd_difference_seven_pm = odd_time
                    odd_difference_seven_pm = odd_time.replace(hour=19, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
                    odd_difference_seven_pm= odd_difference_seven_pm - odd_time


                    if odd_time.weekday() == 4:  # Saturday
                        odd_time = odd_time + timedelta(days=3)
                        odd_time = odd_time.replace(hour=8, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
                    elif odd_time.weekday() == 5:  # Saturday
                        odd_time = odd_time + timedelta(days=2)
                        odd_time = odd_time.replace(hour=8, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
                    elif odd_time.weekday() == 6:  # Sunday
                        odd_time = odd_time + timedelta(days=1)
                        odd_time = odd_time.replace(hour=8, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)      

                                        
                    #
                    time_diff = (even_time - odd_time).total_seconds()/60
 
                    time_diff_list.append(time_diff)


                    df.at[index, 'time_difference'] = time_diff + odd_difference_seven_pm.total_seconds()/60


                previous_odd_timestamp = None
                
                
        elif row["interaction_count"] % 2 != 0:
            previous_odd_timestamp = row["timestamp"]
```

its strange because for two different outputs but that should be passed through the "Block 3" have different outputs.

first input/output its below and its worked right, when you can see 'time_difference' = 60.81 minutes.

```html
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2023-05-05 18:31:51.302",
    "actor_name": "User_1",
    "type": "ChatMessage",
    "message": "message_User_1",
    "actor_type": "end-user",
    "date": "2023-05-05",
    "time": "18:31:51.302000",
    "interaction_count": 11,
    "time_difference": "NaN",
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2023-05-08 08:32:40.076",
    "actor_name": "User_2",
    "type": "ChatMessage",
    "message": "message_User_2",
    "actor_type": "agent",
    "date": "2023-05-08",
    "time": "08:32:40.076000",
    "interaction_count": 12,
    "time_difference": 60.812900,
  }
]
```

Works right. 29 minutes at friday (19:00 - 18:31) + (08:32 - 08:00) = 60.80

But when i try with this other data, i got back a NaN value at "Time difference"

```html
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2023-05-05 08:37:43.902",
    "actor_name": "User_1",
    "type": "ChatMessage",
    "message": "Message_user_1",
    "actor_type": "end-user",
    "date": "2023-05-05",
    "time": "08:37:43.902000",
    "interaction_count": 23,
    "time_difference": "NaN",
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2023-05-09 15:37:21.645",
    "actor_name": "User_2",
    "type": "ChatMessage",
    "message": "Message_user_2",
    "actor_type": "agent",
    "date": "2023-05-09",
    "time": "15:37:21.645000",
    "interaction_count": 24,
    "time_difference": "NaN",
  }
]
```

I can see the error because it match all necessary conditions.

Its between 8 and 19 hours, >= friday, odd_time its equal >= 4 (its 4, friday) and odd_time.weekday is different of even_time.weekday(1, tuesday). Someone can give me a light about it?

Comment: Look at `if 8 < odd_time.hour < 19:` That condition is false if `odd_time.hour` is 8.

Comment: Oh, what a shame that i dont saw that. Can you coment in some way that i can accept?

Comment: To be honest we don't usually write full answers when the issue is only a typo. Good that we found the problem, anyway!